# How do I update a table by data order in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL,
but the problem is that my data isn't organized in a proper data order.

For example, the first row of my table is '2017-05-30', and last row is '2017-02-23'.
So I want to "sort" my table by date.

I'm not asking about

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY DATE;
```

I want to "update" my table.

How can I do this?

Comment: Rows in a relational database are **not** "sorted", so you can't "update" your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sort a PostgreSQL table in the sense you ask.

In relational algebra, the order of the rows is unimportant and there is no guarantee that rows in a table are stored in any specific order. There is also no way to ensure that rows are returned in a particular order unless you specify the order specifically e.g. by using the `ORDER BY`. Otherwise, you shouldn't rely on the order of the returned rows.

As pointed out the in comments, RDBMS may rearrange the order of rows in query results for optimization purposes and so on.

You can, if you like, add a new sequence number field using `row_number()` indicating the ranks of rows with respect to your order (e.g. the date field).

Comment: Also, the DBMS may re-arrange rows as it sees fit.